# Extract relevant text from PDF files using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tesseract

Looking out to extract only the relevant text from whole PDF file using python and store the output data into particular columns of Excel. I have tried to solve it but not able to extract the particular text values only.

Here is the screenshot for the sample output which needs to be extracted :

[image]

**I want to extract Invoice No, Order No, and Order total values in different columns of excel.**

What I have tried so far :

```
import pdfplumber
pdf = pdfplumber.open('file.pdf')
page = pdf.pages[0]
text = page.extract_text()
print(text)
pdf.close()
```

But not getting the exact output from it. Using the above script !

Please suggest !!

Comment: It would be better if you posted what is the current output you are getting for the sample input you've shown here

Comment: just want to confirm it before offering possible solution here - do you need invoice No as part of the extracted data or just 2013-05-12 for invoice No for example?

Comment: Just need the Invoice No value only  2013-05-12

Answer (score 0):

If you want the values for unit price, quantity.... You might want to use Reg-Ex for this.

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp, you can read up here.

Then you can find a suitable data structure to store the data. Then make a relevant database.